# How to exit a javascript "for" loop within a "foreach array" loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to create a new sets of arrays from the given arrays of phones based on given total cost array at a certain condition when the phones array is looped for the prices.

Fore each of the shared prices, I will like to loop through the phone objects, to test the price by dividing the current share amount with the current phone price. If the division is not more than 120 then the result become the quantity to be used, decimal results is "ceiled" to get an integer.

Then, for that iteration, other variables such as names, model and calculated price are added to respective list. The current phone object is then removed from the phone list and the next iteration for the shared price takes over until the loop is complete.

This code is generating more or less than the expected result and the phone objects is not removed as there are repetition in the outcomes.

`HTML` Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="number" id="amount-input">
    <button id="calculate" onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button>

    <h4>Serial List</h4>
    <p class="result" id="serial-view"></p>
    <h4>Names List</h4>
    <p class="result" id="name-view"></p>
    <h4>Models List</h4>
    <p class="result" id="model-view"></p>
    <h4>Quantity List</h4>
    <p class="result" id="quantity-view"></p>
    <h4>Price List</h4>
    <p class="result" id="price-view"></p>
    <h4>Amounts List</h4>
    <p class="result" id="amount-view"></p>
    <h4>Sub Total</h4>
    <p class="result" id="subtotal-view"></p>
    <h4>VAT @ 5%</h4>
    <p class="result" id="vat-view"></p>
    <h4>Gross</h4>
    <p class="result" id="gross-view"></p>


    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
const phones = [
     { name: "BLACKBERRY", model: "BB253", price: 33000 },
     { name: "IPHONE", model: "IPO3", price: 55750 },
     { name: "SAMSUNG", model: "NOTE 4", price: 70000 },
     { name: "NOKIA", model: "WINDOWS", price: 78000 },
     { name: "SAMSUNG", model: "GALAXY A2", price: 93500 },
     { name: "INFINIX", model: "HOT 5", price: 42700 },
     { name: "NOKIA", model: "N347", price: 32550 },
     { name: "TECNO", model: "T154", price: 58500 },
     { name: "LENOVO", model: "Z5S", price: 76250 },
     { name: "NOKIA", model: "9 PURVIEW", price: 195500 },
     { name: "SAMSUNG", model: "NOTE 3", price: 55000 },
     { name: "MOTOROLA", model: "M126", price: 25000 },
     { name: "INFINIX", model: "NOTE 3", price: 55000 },
     { name: "NOKIA", model: "N650", price: 34600 },
     { name: "SAMSUNG", model: "SN330", price: 25800 },
     { name: "IPHONE", model: "IPX", price: 81500 },
     { name: "NOKIA", model: "N3.2", price: 63200 },
     { name: "LG", model: "V30", price: 92300 },
     { name: "GOOGLE", model: "PIXEL 2", price: 61000 },
     { name: "ONEPLUS", model: "5T", price: 49300 },
     { name: "ZTE", model: "AXON M", price: 56000 },
     { name: "NOKIA", model: "N8", price: 58000 },
     { name: "SAMSUNG", model: "J3", price: 48000 }
];

const serialView = document.getElementById("serial-view");
const nameView = document.getElementById("name-view");
const modelView = document.getElementById("model-view");
const qtyView = document.getElementById("quantity-view");
const priceView = document.getElementById("price-view");
const amountView = document.getElementById("amount-view");
const subTotalView = document.getElementById("subtotal-view");
const VATView = document.getElementById("vat-view");
const grossView = document.getElementById("gross-view");


function calculate() {

     // window.location.reload(false);

     // Initialize Views and Lists
     serialView.innerText = "";
     nameView.innerText = "";
     modelView.innerText = "";
     qtyView.innerText = "";
     priceView.innerText = "";
     amountView.innerText = "";
     subTotalView.innerText = "";
     VATView.innerText = "";
     grossView.innerText = "";

     serialList = [];
     workingSerialList = [];
     ratioList = [];
     sharedList = [];
     modelList = [];
     nameList = [];
     qtyList = [];
     priceList = [];

     // Get amount value from input box
     let totalAmount = document.getElementById("amount-input").value;

     let actualCost = 100 / 105;
     let vatElement = 5 / 105;

     const subTotal = (parseFloat(totalAmount) * actualCost).toFixed(2);
     const totalVAT = (parseFloat(totalAmount) * vatElement).toFixed(2);

     // Get minimum and maximum serial numbers
     var min, max = 0;
     if (totalAmount < 1000000) {
          min = 1;
          max = 3;
     } else if (totalAmount <= 20000000) {
          min = 2;
          max = 4;
     } else if (totalAmount <= 500000000) {
          min = 4;
          max = 6;
     } else if (totalAmount <= 500000000) {
          min = 4;
          max = 7;
     }

     // Get the last list number to work with
     let lastNumber = randomLast(min, max);

     // Produce and show random serial numbers list
     for (let i = 1; i <= lastNumber; i++) {
          serialList.push(i);
     }

     // Create a working serial to prevent original list
     for (i = 0; i < serialList.length; i++) {
          workingSerialList[i] = serialList[i];
     }

     // Produce and show random ratio lists
     ratioList = shuffleList(workingSerialList);
     //      // ratioView.innerText = ratioList;

     // Calculate and show Ratio List total
     const ratioListTotal = ratioList.reduce((currentTotal, ratio) => {
          return parseInt(ratio + currentTotal);
     }, 0);

     // Calculate and display Shared Amounts
     ratioList.forEach((ratio) => {
          let x = parseInt(ratio) / parseInt(ratioListTotal);
          x = (x * subTotal).toFixed(2);
          sharedList.push(x);
     });

     //  Set Phone model, name, quantity and price for each amount array
     sharedList.forEach((share) => {

          // Loop through the phones array to test for a matching price
          loop1:
          for(let i=0; i < phones.length; i++) {

               share = parseFloat(share);

               let pricetTest = phones[i].price;
               let qtyTest = share / parseFloat(pricetTest);

               // If a price is matched
               if(qtyTest <= 120) {
                    
                    // Perform these actions on the current phone loop
                    let itemQty = Math.ceil(qtyTest);
                    let itemPrice = parseFloat(share / parseInt(itemQty)).toFixed(2);

                    modelList.push(phones[i].model);
                    nameList.push(phones[i].name);
                    qtyList.push(itemQty);
                    priceList.push(itemPrice);

                    // Remove the current phone from the list to prevent it from being tested again
                    phones.splice(i, 1);

                    // Stop this loop for the current share price
                    break loop1;

               }
               
               
          }

     });

     serialView.innerText = serialList;
     nameView.innerText = nameList;
     modelView.innerText = modelList;
     qtyView.innerText = qtyList;
     priceView.innerText = priceList;
     amountView.innerText = sharedList;
     subTotalView.innerText = subTotal;
     VATView.innerText = totalVAT;
     grossView.innerText = parseFloat(totalAmount).toFixed(2);

     
}

// Function to get random number between ranges
function randomLast(m, x) {
     m = Math.ceil(m);
     x = Math.floor(x);
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - m + 1) + m);
}

// Random number generator
function randomNum(min, max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

// Shuffler function
function shuffleList(array) {
     array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
     return array;
}
```

I am getting fine results until the input is more than a few millions which is weird.

Comment: `break` breaks out of any for loop, regardless where it is

Comment: Yes, but the logic is not performing the intended operation before `if` condition. The list are either too many or too small. Thanks

Comment: huh? did you want to break out of the forEach? you can use `.some` or `.every` instead

Comment: No sir, I want to break out of the nested `for` loop when the condition is met and it has performed the actions. It is doing that presently but either not complete or too many times before breaking the loop.

Comment: use `break` to do that = if your logic is wrong, that doesn't mean that `break` doesn't work like you claim

Comment: `phones.splice(i, 0);` is removing `0` items, starting at position `i` - that is it is not removing anything. To remove the item at index i, use: `phones.splice(i, 1);`.

Comment: I have corrected that (kindly see the new problem), it's working problem still persists after higher figures

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : So if I understand what you want to do :

```js
const phones = [
    { name: "BLACKBERRY", model: "BB253", price: 33000 },
    { name: "IPHONE", model: "IPO3", price: 55750 },
    { name: "SAMSUNG", model: "NOTE 4", price: 70000 },
    { name: "NOKIA", model: "WINDOWS", price: 78000 },
    { name: "SAMSUNG", model: "GALAXY A2", price: 93500 }
];

const modelList = new Set([]);
nameList = new Set([]);
qtyList = new Set([]);
priceList = new Set([]);

const sharedPrices = [200000, 150000, 300000, 250000];

for (const sharedPrice of sharedPrices) {
    phones.forEach(phone => {
        const { price } = phone;
        const qty = Math.floor(sharedPrice / price);
        if (qty <= 120) {
            const { model } = phone;
            const { name } = phone;
            modelList.add(model);
            nameList.add(name);
            qtyList.add(qty);
            priceList.add(price);
        }
    })
}
console.log(modelList)
console.log(nameList)
console.log(qtyList)
console.log(priceList)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Instant error when I used that. The actual list, I mean the phones and shared prices list are actually very long and the iterations are lengthy so I'm getting wierd outcomes. The main problems are
The `slice` method failed to remove the indexed object from the list and
The `for` loop is either not complete or too many

Comment: Then you should try to use a Set and use the delete method. If all your items are unique, a Set would do it.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a short example on the expected result. I'm not sure to get your point in the end :-/

Comment: Okay. As I have 4 elements in the sharedPrices lists, the `foreach` iterations is supposed to run 4 times and each time, the nested  `for` loop should iterate over it's 5 elements until the condition is met. If the condition is met, it should perform the actions and start another `foreach` iteration. Now, the iterations are either too many or too short. I don't even know which iteration is.

Comment: Your condition is always true :  if (qtyTest <= 120) so you're expecting 4 new arrays with a length of 20 ?

Comment: Yes my condition will always be met at some point on the actual lists. And once that happens, it should fulfill the instructions and move to the next iteration, removing the tested index until the foreach loop is concluded. But the results is more or less than the loops. I think I placed the break and or the slice in wrong places.